# Any good advice on using emacs for C++ project?

Tags: c++, emacs

I'm looking for a good article on using emacs as C/C++ IDE.

Something like Steve Yegge's ["Effective emacs"](http://steve.yegge.googlepages.com/effective-emacs).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No specific article, really, but I've found [EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki) to be full of useful information. Consider checking out these entries:

- [CPlusPlus](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/CPlusPlus) as a starting point for many C++-related articles, and
- [CppTemplate](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/CppTemplate) to define a template that can give you a good skeleton when you start new files

Answer (score 15):

I've recently stumbled upon this [article](http://www.physics.ucsb.edu/~taro/comp/tips/emacs/emacs-c-dev.html) which is quite good.

EDIT: Yep the link is no longer valid. It seems like they've changed their url recently and it doesn't redirect properly. Hopefully it will be back soon. Anyway the article was called "Benjamin Rutt's Emacs C development tips". I managed to find a copy [here](http://xugx2007.blogspot.com/2007/06/benjamin-rutts-emacs-c-development-tips.html).

Comment: For anyone wanting to read this, here is a link to the article: http://xugx2007.blogspot.com/2007/06/benjamin-rutts-emacs-c-development-tips.html

Answer (score 13):

I'm planning to write such article in near future, but you can now take [my configuration](http://xtalk.msk.su/~ott/common/emacs/rc/emacs-rc-cedet.el.html) of [Cedet](http://cedet.sf.net) + Emacs, that helps me to effectively edit C++ sources.
If you'll have questions, you could ask me directly

Comment: I wrote article on use CEDET for C/C++ - http://alexott.net/en/writings/emacs-devenv/EmacsCedet.html

Answer (score 7):

Be aware that Emacs' C++ mode is based on only regular expressions, not a grammar.  Hence, the syntax highlighting is not based strictly on the syntax of the language itself, but rather is largely based on commonplace formatting.  The Emacs syntax highlighting of C++ often makes mistakes.

The problem is not limited to syntax hightlighting.  The same defective design applies to the automatic formatting.  All this said, I have been using only Emacs for all of my editing of C++ source code for over 20 years, since the cfront days.  (I usually turn off electric key bindings, because of Emacs' defective regex-based design.  Regexes do not have enough expressive power to describe the C++ syntax accurately.

Comment: I have spent a lot of frustrating years developing in C++ without good support from editors. Microsoft Visual Studio is undoubtedly the best C++ editor out there. But on Unix based world, you are on your own. Source Insight is good but works on M$ only! I feel the compiler should generate the cross reference data as it knows best. Hope clang will fill that gap.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [ggtags](https://github.com/leoliu/ggtags) and [irony-mode](https://github.com/Sarcasm/irony-mode). Other then that you may want to use [helm-ag](https://github.com/syohex/emacs-helm-ag) to search ("grep") for strings in your codebase.